# call in x86 real mode does not save return address

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bootloader, real-mode

I'm trying to write a real mode bootloader and I'm currently having problems trying to enable the A20 line. Here's my code so far, I'm assembling with NASM:

```
[bits 16]

[global _start]

jmp _start

bios_print:
 lodsb
 test al, al
 jz bios_print_done
 mov ah, 0x0E
 mov bh, 0
 int 0x10
 jmp bios_print

bios_print_done:
 ret

a20_is_enabled:
 push ds
 push si
 push es
 push di

 xor ax, ax
 mov ds, ax
 mov si, BOOT_ID_OFFS

 mov ax, BOOT_ID_OFFS_PLUS_1MB_SEGM
 mov es, ax
 mov di, BOOT_ID_OFFS_PLUS_1MB_OFFS

 cmp word [es:di], BOOT_ID

 mov ax, 1
 jne a20_is_enabled_done

 mov ax, word [ds:si]
 xor ax, ax
 mov [ds:si], ax

 cmp word [es:di], BOOT_ID

 push ax
 xor ax, ax
 mov [ds:si], ax
 pop ax

 mov ax, 1
 jne a20_is_enabled_done

 mov ax, 0

a20_is_enabled_done:
 pop di
 pos es
 pop si
 pop ds

 ret

a20_enable_bios:
 mov ax, 0x2403
 int 0x15
 jc a20_enable_bios_failure
 test ah, ah
 jnz a20_enable_bios_failure

 mov ax, 0x2401
 int 0x15
 jc a20_enable_bios_failure
 test ah, ah
 jnz a20_enable_bios_failure

 mov ax, 1
 jmp a20_enable_bios_done

a20_enable_bios_failure:
 mov ax, 0

a20_enable_bios_done:
 ret

a20_enable:

 push si

 mov si, word MSG_A20_TRY_BIOS
 call bios_print

 pop si

 call a20_enable_bios

 test ax, ax
 jz a20_enable_failure

 call a20_is_enabled

 test ax, ax
 jnz a20_enable_success

a20_enable_failure:

 push si

 mov si, word MSG_A20_FAILURE
 call bios_print

 pop si

 mov ax, 0
 jmp a20_enable_done

a20_enable_success:

 push si

 mov si, word MSG_A20_SUCCESS
 call bios_print

 pop si

 mov ax, 1

a20_enable_done:
 ret

_start:
 xor ax, ax
 mov ds, ax

 cld

 cli

 push si

 mov si, word MSG_GREETING
 call bios_print

 pop si

 call a20_enable

 test ax, ax
 jz boot_error

 ; TODO

boot_error:
 jmp boot_error

BOOT_ID equ 0xAA55
BOOT_ID_OFFS equ 0x7DFE
BOOT_ID_OFFS_PLUS_1MB_SEGM equ 0xFFFF
BOOT_ID_OFFS_PLUS_1MB_OFFS equ BOOT_ID_OFFS + (0x1 << 20) - (BOOT_ID_OFFS_PLUS_1MB_SEGM << 4)

MSG_GREETING db 'Hello from the bootloader', 0xA, 0xD, 0
MSG_A20_TRY_BIOS db 'Trying to enable A20 line via BIOS interrupt', 0xA, 0xD, 0
MSG_A20_SUCCESS db 'Successfully enabled A20 line', 0xA, 0xD, 0
MSG_A20_FAILURE db 'Failed to enable A20 line', 0xA, 0xD, 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw BOOT_ID
```

The problem is the function `a20_is_enabled` which is supposed to check if the A20 line is enabled after `a20_enable_bios` has activated it via a BIOS interrupt (I know this is not foolproof, more code will follow here). When I debug the code everything seems to be fine until `call a20_is_enabled`. The processor does then indeed perform a near call to to correct address here *but* no return address is pushed onto the stack (which I have verified with gdb). So when `ret` is executed in `a20_is_enabled`, the instruction pointer is set to some garbage address. Why is this?

EDIT: note that there is not `ORG 0x7C00` at the beginning of my assembly code. This is because I first create an elf file so that I can debug my code using gdb and that doesn't play well with `ORG`, So I actually do this:

```
nasm -f elf32 -g -F dwarf boot.asm -o boot.o
ld -Ttext=0x7c00 -melf_i386 boot.o -o boot.elf
objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin
```

Comment: I highly recommend BOCHS for real mode debugging of things like bootloaders and other real mode code. Unlike GDB, BOCHs has proper understanding of real mode segment:offeset addressing. BOCHs only has limited symbolic debugging but this is usually not a big deal for stepping through things as small as a bootloader.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I have not used BOCHs before but that sounds sensible. As to org 0x7c00: that is sort of related to  the fact that I use gdb, I will edit the question.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I have updated the question, the ORG line is missing because I create an ELF file with debug information and that doesn't seem to work with ORG. Maybe the command I use to link is not appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally one might close this question as it is caused by a typographical error but the error isn't necessarily obvious at first. One has to pay close attention in a debugger observing the instructions that are being executed.

This had me scratching my head since when I looked in the debugger the sequence:

```
 push ds
 push si
 push es
 push di

 ; Snip other code

 pop di
 pos es
 pop si
 pop ds
 ret
```

only showed the processor executing 3 `POP`s and a `ret` when there are clearly 4 `POP` instructions. Because the processor isn't doing enough POPs the return address is incorrect and `ret` returns to the wrong part of memory and causes unexpected behavior.

The problem is rather trivial and because of a stroke of bad luck an instruction is produced without error but isn't the instruction you want. If you look closely this is the culprit:

```
 pos es
```

There is a typo. `POS` should be `POP`. My brain didn't catch it at first. `pos` is being treated as a label and `es` is a segment override so can appear on a line by itself. This caused the instruction `es pop si` to be produced.

Clearly the fix is to change it to:

```
 pop es
```

Comment: Oh my God, I have looked at this for minutes and didn't see it. Great catch.

Comment: Nice spotting. I've wanted to get an optional warning for this into NASM for years. Refer to [Add label-no-colon warning](https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392632).

Comment: @ecm : I agree. The warning about a label with no colon on a line with an instruction would have been handy here lol. This was one of the first questions after waking up and I didn't realize the typo after looking at the original code repeatedly. BOCHs didn't do me any favors except to tell me there were 3 pop instructions. It remained a mystery to me until I did an objdump of the code and objdump was kind enough to point out the instruction was `es pop si`. It would have been handy for BOCHs to tell me that was what was encoded. Once I saw that and finally looked close the problem was obvious

Comment: @ecm : what is funny is that when I got to figuring it out I was about to leave a comment and point out the problem and close it as a simple typographical error and thought hell I spent enough time on this dumb problem that maybe it is worthy of an answer for the future. I am not a fan of labels without colons. MASM didn't help since there are rules about the colon being in data and code that I never liked. Anyway, I'd like to see BOCHs show us a better decoding and NASM with more warnings and I think your patch is a good idea for that and the other cases.

Comment: 100% agreed.  If NASM doesn't warn you about this by default, that's bad.  If it can't warn you about this *at all*, that's terrible.  `label: prefix` on a line by itself seems really unlikely, and if you do want that you can do it with a colon to make it clear.  `label prefix` should IMO never appear on a line by itself in sane source code, even if the label isn't easily mistakeable for an instruction.  An option to simply disable accepting non-`:` labels could also or instead be useful, @ecm, to let the assembler enforce standard NASM style.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: If label-no-colon was accepted as a warning, you could specify it as a warning that should be treated as an error. That would serve the same purpose as to "disable accepting non-`:` labels".

Comment: If NASM maintainers decide to accept `:` as an optional label terminator, I advocate to tolerate this terminator both when the symbol is *defined* and *refered*, see https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#SymbolName